# What's the differences between おかず and 食べ物

Tags: words, meaning, food

I'm confused about how to use two words おかず and 食べ物, which all defined "food" as I search. What's the differences about them? Really thank you if you give me some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **clear** difference between the two.  (I feel for you because I have seen 「おかず」 defined wrongly in smaller bilingual dictionaries.)

「[食]{た}べ[物]{もの}」 refers to any and all kinds of food; It just includes ***everything people eat***.  Anything edible is called 「食べ物」.

「おかず」 is different.  It is what you eat ***with*** rice (or bread) in a meal.  It refers to the entree and all of the side dishes.  Rice, bread, snacks and desserts are ***not*** called 「おかず」 among Japanese-speakers.

This should give you a good idea of what おかず is:

http://image.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=&p=%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9A

Answer (score 3):

I think おかず refers to side dishes accompanied with rice, while 食べ物 refers to 'food' in general.

When Japanese or Chinese eat meals at home, there's usually a bowl of rice per person and several dishes (e.g. fish, meat, vegetable) in the middle. Those dishes are called おかず.